# Perl - search and save results in a array

Tags: perl, variables, search

I'm trying to search a text in xml file and trying to save result in a array.
Basically it is searching for string "http://sdsad.com/a.html"

Perl script

```
my $infile = 'build.xml';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";   
my @finaldata = ();
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    print "$1\n" if ($_ =~ /(http:.*html)/);
    push (@finaldata, $1);
    }

print "$finaldata[$1]\n";
```

It does output http://sdsad.com/a.html; 
but it does not save result in a array or a variable?

or is there any one liner to achieve desire output?

Comment: `push @finaldata, /(http:.*html)/;`. And at the end, `print "$_\n" for @finaldata;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are pushing `$1` onto the array whether or not the regex matched. That will probably give you several elements of the array set to `undef`. You should do this instead

```
while (<$input>) {
   if ( /(http:.*html)/ ) {
      print "$1\n";
      push @finaldata, $1;
   }
}
```

Also, in the line

```
print "$finaldata[$1]\n"
```

you are trying to index the array using a *string* captured from a regex match.

It should be

```
print "$finaldata[0]\n"
```

or perhaps

```
print "$_\n" for @finaldata
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` doesn't exist outside of your loop.

You need to access your data like this:

```
foreach(@finaldata){
print "$_\n";
}
```

I would also consider rewriting:

```
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
        if ($_ =~ /(http:.*html)/) {
            print "$1\n";
            push @finaldata, $1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're adding $1 as a value, but in print you're trying to use it as an index. Try:

```
print join(',', @finaldata);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and your help!